# problems on compling multiple tex files

Tags: errors, multiple-files

```
\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
    \vspace{1em}
    \centering
    %  \label{tab:name}
    \begin{tabular}{c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c}
        %   \hline
        t      & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 \\ \hline
        Node 1 & 4 &   &   & 2 &   &   &   & 1 &   & \\ \hline
        Node 2 &   & 5 &   &   &   & 2 &   &   &   & \\ \hline
        Node 3 & 1 &   &   & 3 &   &   &   & 7 &   & \\ \hline
        Node 4 &   & 1 &   &   & 5 &   &   &   & 2 & \\ \hline
        Node 5 &   &   &   &   &   & 7 &   &   &   & \\ \hline
        $\mathcal{C}_t$    & 2 & 2 & 3 & 3 & 4 & 3 & 4 & 4 & 4 &4 \\
        %\hline    
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{table}{The amount of energy harvested of each sensor in slot $t-1$,$t\in[1,10]$ is given by the above table.}
\end{minipage}

Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup. ... 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 \\ \hline
Missing } inserted. ... 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 \\ \hline
```

I am trying to compile multiple files together to get one thesis PDF file. This piece of script works perfectly fine on its single status. But, when I tried to compile it, it always has problems. I have no idea. Typically, it has problems when I have align, array, and algorithmic operations.

By the way, I use one template with certain class file to combine all the files. Did anyone have similar issues? Thanks for your help.

Comment: welcome to tex.sx.  it would be much easier to help you if you could provide a small compilable example, beginning with `\documentclass` and endoing with `\end{document}`.  otherwise, we'll have to guess, and our crystal balls are very murky.

Comment: I'm afraid I am unable to replicate the error message you say you're getting.

Comment: You should probably have `\captionof{table}{...}` instead of `\caption{table}{...}`, and `\captionof` requires either the `caption` or `capt-of` package, but other than that your snippet works fine here.

Comment: try to compile your thesis in adding files one by one.

Comment: You should be able to narrow your problem down by finding out exacly what file is causing the problem, and what line of code - by systematically including and commenting code. From this you can make a MWE (see description on this page). For now I am voting to close this question, as other users can not replicate your problem.